# Matplotlib add subtitle to figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, title, subplot

I want to add a title to my figure that contains several subplots.

Here is my code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

    plt.figure(figsize = (15, 80))
    for i, audio, rate, name in zip(range(len(audios)), audios, rates, names):
        plt.subplot(len(audios), 1, i+1)
        plt.plot(rate, audio)
        plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.title(name)
    plt.subtitle('Figure 1: Plot amplitude of signal')
    plt.show()
```

The error I get is : `module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'subtitle'`
I can't figure out why this doesn't work since it is written that way in the matplotlib documentation ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is `.suptitle`, not `.subtitle`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is correct, the `pyplot` library has *no* `.subtitle` function, only a [`.suptitle` function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle).

So you should fix this with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.figure(figsize = (15, 80))
for i, audio, rate, name in zip(range(len(audios)), audios, rates, names):
    plt.subplot(len(audios), 1, i+1)
    plt.plot(rate, audio)
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.title(name)
plt.suptitle('Figure 1: Plot amplitude of signal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should have been posted as a comment given your golden badge and that it was a typo error but anyway

Comment: @Bazingaa: I'm not really sure it was a typo in the "strict" sense. After all `.subtitle` would be a valid candidate. So I think it was not a "typing mistake". It is more a classical "misread" and then use it that way.